# php - how to list differences between two arrays

Tags: php, laravel

I need to list the differences after updating an array:

```
$current = [1, 2, 3];
$new     = [3, 4, 5];
```

List example:

```
- number 1 removed
- number 2 removed
- number 3 keep
- number 4 added
- number 5 added
```

How can I do this on PHP/Laravel?

Comment: Utilizing [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff) and doing some iterations to display the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

Different apporach

```
$current = [1, 2, 3];
$new = [3, 4, 5];

//initial variables
$list = [];
const ADDED = 1;
const KEPT = 2;
const DELETED = 3;
const STATUSES = array(
    ADDED => 'added',
    KEPT => 'kept',
    DELETED => 'deleted',
);

//populate $list array with elements of your old/new arrays with corresponding action performed
$list = array_fill_keys(array_diff($new, $current), ADDED);
$list += array_fill_keys(array_intersect($current, $new), KEPT);
$list += array_fill_keys(array_diff($current, $new), DELETED);

//you can sort your array here
ksort($list);

//output actions in your array
foreach ($list as $number => $action) {
    printf("- number %d %s\n", $number, STATUSES[$action]);
}
```

Output:

```
- number 1 deleted
- number 2 deleted
- number 3 kept
- number 4 added
- number 5 added
```

Comment: You could reduce the switch to something like: `printf("number %d %s", $number, [ADDED => 'added', KEPT => 'kept', DELETED => 'deleted'][$action]);`

Comment: @Progrock, that's true. Thanks for a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$current = [1, 2, 3];
$new     = [3, 4, 5];

$removed = array_diff($current, $new);
$kept    = array_intersect($current, $new);
$added   = array_diff($new, $current);

$result = [];
foreach(['removed', 'kept', 'added'] as $outcome) {
    $result += array_fill_keys($$outcome, $outcome);
}
ksort($result);

foreach($result as $n => $outcome) {
    echo 'number ', $n, ' ', $outcome, ".\n";
}
```

Output:

```
number 1 removed.
number 2 removed.
number 3 kept.
number 4 added.
number 5 added.
```

As this looks to be a similar approach to Tajni's here's an alternative one-liner (without the key sort):

```
<?php
foreach (
    array_replace(
        ...array_map(
            'array_fill_keys', 
            [$current, $new, array_intersect($current, $new)], 
            ['removed', 'added', 'kept']
        )
    )
    as $n => $outcome)
{
    echo "number $n $outcome.\n";
}
```

Comment: Method here is pretty much the same as Tajni's earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
$fullDiffs = array_merge(array_diff($current, $new), array_diff($new, $current));

foreach($fullDiffs as $i => $id){
  if(in_array($id, $current) && in_array($id, $new)){
    // keep it
  }
  if(in_array($id, $current) && !in_array($id, $new)){
    // remove it
  }
  if(!in_array($id, $current) && in_array($id, $new)){
    // add it
  }
}
```